# php - Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null and remove alert laravel

Tags: php, laravel, photo

I am newbie in Laravel so i really need some help. I want to ask when 
I commented the part 'photo' => required why if I update without entering the photo it shows some error like  call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null. So the real question is I want to update without entering photo and it should still to be updated.

This is my code in Controller to upload photo

```
    public function update($id, UpdateBannerRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    //get original file name
    $filename = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    $input['photo'] =  $filename;
    Input::file('photo')->move($this->path, $filename);
    $banner = $this->BannerRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

    if (empty($banner)) {
        Flash::error('Banner not found');

        return redirect(route('banner.index'));
    }

    $banner = $this->BannerRepository->update($input, $id);

    Flash::success('Banner updated successfully.');

    return redirect(route('banner.index'));
}
```

This is the code on my model

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Banner extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

```
public $table = 'banners';


protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


public $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description',
    'photo',        
    'status'
];

protected $casts = [
    'title' => 'string',
    'description' => 'string',
    'photo' => 'string',       
    'status' => 'integer'
];



public static $rules = [
    'title' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    //'photo' => 'required',
    'status' => 'required'
];
```

}

[image: This is the view]
[image: and This is the error]

Comment: `Input::file('photo')` is not an object

Comment: So when the update without entering the photo will appear 'no image found' photo like this http://imgur.com/a/qzDVc

Comment: @Scuzzy hello thanks for response, so what should i do for this problem?

Comment: validate your input if the error goes away when you do choose a file. Your form screenshot has "no file chosen". Which would explain why `Input::file('photo')` is null

Comment: @Scuzzy can you make the code because I'm really newbie in laravel: DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$validator = Validator::make(
                    $request->all(),
                    array(
                        'photo' => 'required',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'photo' => 'Please choose file',
                    )
                );
```

If Photo is not mandatory directly use this

```
if(!empty($request->photo)){
   //do something
}
else{
  Flash::error('Banner not provided');
  return redirect(route('banner.index'));
}
```

Hope this will help.. let me know if any issue..Thank you

your update function would look like

```
     public function update($id, UpdateBannerRequest $request)
        {
            $input = $request->all();
            $banner = $this->BannerRepository->findWithoutFail($id);
            if(!empty($request->photo)){
               //do something for saving the name of file in database and other value respectively using
    //         $filename = Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    //         $banner->photo = $filename;
            }
            else{
               Flash::error('Banner not provided');
               return redirect(route('banner.index'));
            }
            $banner->save();
            Flash::success('Banner updated successfully.');
            return redirect(route('banner.index'));
        }
```

Comment: thanks for help :DD is $ validator put in model Banner.php?

Comment: i prefer to put in controller

Comment: okay thanks, and can you make the full code if photo is not mandatory? because im really newbie in Laravel :D :D

Comment: yeahh sure i do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153312/discussion-between-rohit-shah-and-sahat-riyanto).

Comment: Thank you for helping Rohit shah: D but Im not using your code so i got the answer and it's worked like this http://imgur.com/a/vuJCL

Answer (score 0):

The simplest validation required would be to test if `Input::hasFile('photo')`, this should be placed before you call `Input::file('photo')->getClientOriginalName()`

```
if( Input::hasFile('photo') == false )
{
  Flash::error('Banner not provided');
  return redirect(route('banner.index'));
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files

Comment: Thanks for help :D but it still didint work this is the code http://imgur.com/a/9wqCM and this is the error http://imgur.com/a/2znco

Comment: I tried putting before Input :: file ('photo') -> getClientOriginalName () and still show the same error http://imgur.com/a/ea62h

Comment: oops, I stuffed up a bracket change to `if( Input::hasFile('photo') == false )`

Comment: Its okay :DD and thank you photo upload function has worked but when I try to update without entering photo, like the example I just changed in the description section or the title was not working so the title and description are not updated

Comment: Hopefully you should have enough to be able to determine when a file is provided or not and update only what you need

Answer (score 0):

You should check bellow code.

`if(isset(Input::file('photo'))`

Before work with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but how to make it in my code because i really newbie in Laravel :D

Comment: $file = $request->file('photo');
        if(isset($file)) {
           //do upload code here
        }else{
            //if file is not exist
        }

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i dont get it, can u make the full code please i really need some help :DDD